# Identify location Using coordinates

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID         Start_Datetime       End_Datetime         Longitude   Latitude
2.011e+09  2011-02-01 00:47:35  2011-02-01 00:57:05  -73.98839   40.75504
```

I want to identify if each row happened in one of my locations of interest, e.g. an airport. For this I am doing the following:

```
tol <- 0.001
for (i in 1:length(DataS$latitude) ){ 
  if(abs(DataSet$latitude[i] - 40.644305) < tol | 
     abs(DataSet$latitude[i] - 40.642160) < tol) 
    if(abs(DataSet$longitude[i] - -73.790517) < tol |
       abs(DataSet$longitude[i] - -73.788895) < tol)
    {
      DataSet$POI[i] <- 1
    } 
}
```

My dataset has over 20 million rows and this code is time consuming. Is there any other way in which I can get this to work more efficiently? Maybe a function in the ggmap package that I adapt to this?

Thanks,

Comment: also, if I understand correctly, the question has nothing to do with coordinates or POIs. it's simply about creating a new column efficiently by conditioning on other columns. consider rewording the title

Comment: vectorise your code using one of the apply-familiy functions. this should be much faster than a for-loop in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following solution: Comparison based on vectors, and test
based on the centers of the rectangles instead of the boundary.

```
test_df <- data.frame(latitute = runif(n = 1000), longitude = runif(n = 1000))

tol <- 0.01

lat1 <- 0.35
lat2 <- 0.37
long1 <- 0.64
long2 <- 0.70

lat12 <- (lat1 + lat2)/2
tol1 <- tol + abs(lat2 - lat1)/2

long12 <- (long1 + long2)/2
tol2 <- tol + abs(long2 - long1)/2


test_df$POI <- abs(test_df$latitute - lat12) < tol1 &
    abs(test_df$longitude - long12) < tol2
```

Comment: This is a much faster option. Thanks!